# "call to deleted constructor of" compiler error for std::runtime_error sub-class

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

I have derived an exception class from `std::runtime_error` in order to add support for streaming to exceptions. I am getting a strange compiler error output with clang that I'm not sure how to resolve?

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wall -I../ -I/usr/local/include Main.cpp -c
Main.cpp:43:19: error: call to deleted constructor of 'EarthException'
            throw EarthException(__FILE__, __LINE__)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../EarthException.hpp:9:12: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
    struct EarthException : public Exception<EarthException>


template <typename TDerived>
    class Exception : public std::runtime_error
    {
        public:
            Exception() : std::runtime_error("") {}

            Exception(const std::string& file, const unsigned line)
                 : std::runtime_error("")
            { 
                stream_ << (file.empty() ? "UNNAMED_FILE" : file) << "[" << line << "]: ";
            }

            virtual ~Exception() {}

            template <typename T>
            TDerived& operator<<(const T& t)
            {
                stream_ << t;
                return static_cast<TDerived&>(*this);
            }

            virtual const char* what() const throw()
            {
                return stream_.str().c_str();
            }

       private:
           std::stringstream stream_;
    };

    struct EarthException : public Exception<EarthException>
    {
        EarthException() {}

        EarthException(const std::string& file, const unsigned line)
            : Exception<EarthException>(file, line) {}

        virtual ~EarthException() {}
    };
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've now added explicit calls to `std::runtime_error("")` as it was pointed out the default constructor on this was marked as `=delete` however the error remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the user-declared destructors in `Exception` and `EarthException`, implicit generation of the move constructor and move assignment operators for these classes is disabled.  And because of the move-only data member `std::stringstream`, implicit copy members are deleted.

However all of that is a distraction.

Your `what` member is doomed:

```
        virtual const char* what() const throw()
        {
            return stream_.str().c_str();
        }
```

This creates an rvalue `std::string` and then returns a pointer into that temporary.  The temporary destructs before the client can ever read the pointer into that temporary.

What you need to do is pass a `std::string` down to the `std::runtime_error` base class.  Then you don't need to hold a `stringstream`, or any other data member.  The only tricky part is initializing the `std::runtime_error` base class with the proper `string`:

```
template <typename TDerived>
    class Exception : public std::runtime_error
    {
            static
            std::string
            init(const std::string& file, const unsigned line)
            {
                std::ostringstream os;
                os << (file.empty() ? "UNNAMED_FILE" : file) << "[" << line << "]: ";
                return os.str();
            }
        public:
            Exception(const std::string& file, const unsigned line)
                : std::runtime_error(init(file, line))
            { 
            }

      private:
          <del>std::stringstream stream_;</del>
```

Now you'll get implicit copy members and things will just work.

Comment: Thanks, very insightful. One problem though is I can no longer stream to the class which was my original intent. Wouldn't holding std::stringstream by a std::unique_ptr solve the problem?

Comment: If you want the exception to be move-only, there's no need to introduce `unique_ptr`.  `stringstream` is also move-only.  You can think of it as its own `unique_ptr`.  But I think you'll also need to store a `std::string` (in addition to that in `runtime_error`.  Since `what` must return a `const char*`, that pointer must point to something permanent (like a data member).  You can't have it point into a temporary.  In a nutshell, design the `what` first, and then do whatever is necessary to support that `what`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I fully understand the issue with returning a const char* to a temporary, that was an oversight on my part! I'm still not entirely clear why it's not compiling if std::stringstream is move only, I assume my class isn't move only in which case I presume I need to provide a move constructor and operator=?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide your own move members if desired.  The user-declared destructors inhibit the compiler from supplying these.  And I don't believe you'll be able to explicitly default them at this time, though you may be able to in the future.  There's a language issue under discussion on committee on this part: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1402

Comment: You are correct, even by removing destructors from the class definition the compiler error remains. Thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 2):

```
Exception(const std::string& file, const unsigned line)
            { 
                stream_ << (file.empty() ? "UNNAMED_FILE" : file) << "[" << line << "]: ";
            }
```

This constructor does not call its base constructor, so the compiler generates a call to the default constructor, `std::runtime_error::runtime_error()`. But `std::runtime_error` does not have a default constructor, which is what the error message is telling you. To fix this, read about `std::runtime_error` and call one of its constructors.

EDIT: okay, here's the **real** problem (not that what I address above isn't a problem, too): the template `Exception` has a data member of type `std::stringstream`; streams cannot be copied, so the compiler can't generate a copy constructor to use for the throw.

Comment: Incidentally, the stuff about "deleted" is a C++11-ism; apparently the default constructor for `std::runtime_error` is marked with `= delete`, which tells the compiler not to generate it, even if it otherwise would. Looks like the error message got a bit tangled up...

Comment: I've now added explicit calls to std::runtime_error("") but still see the error message :(